# in C++11 I would like to get rid of the raw pointers in pimpl idiom

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to get rid of the raw pointer (`parent_`) to the main class in the pimpl idiom. What would be the best way to ag about it. Here is the example:

```
//==============in "widget.h"
class Widget { 
public:
Widget() {};
…
private:
struct Impl;
std::unique_ptr<Impl> pImpl; 
};

//==== in .cpp 
#include "widget.h"
#include "gadget.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Widget::Impl { 
Widget* parent_;
std::string name;
std::vector<double> data;
Gadget g1, g2, g3;

Impl (Widget* parent) : parent_ (parent) {}

};

Widget::Widget() 
: pImpl(std::make_unique<Impl>( this )) 
{}
```

Comment: Why not use a reference `Widget&` and pass `*this`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't!

Raw pointers are fine. Raw **owning** pointers must be replaced with smart ones, but `parent_` doesn't own anything. Leave it be :)

Comment: Actually I agree with you and this is how I use this pattern but just wanted to make sure that I  have not overlooked somethink whoch the experts will catch.

Comment: `Widget` is the owner of an `Impl`, but `Impl` is not an owner of `Widget`.  If you were using shared_ptr, `Widget` would have a strong pointer to `Impl`, and `Impl` would have a weak pointer to `Widget`.  But that's overkill in this situation, because `Impl` is entirely contained within `Widget`, and doesn't leak out.  The lifecycle, ownership, and object management is strongly specified here.  I agree with Quentin (and your own instincts)... I wouldn't change it.

Comment: (I assume `Widget` has an appropriate copy-constructor, or `=delete` on it.  And assignment-operator, or lack thereof.)

Answer (score 2):

The designers of the C++11 Standard Library have been *very* careful in allowing an *incomplete type* to be used for `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`, in certain instances.

Such instances are largely centred around your being able to use these smart pointers with the pImpl idiom. This means that you don't need the bare pointer.

For more details see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl

Comment: Doesn't the OP mean he wants to access the owner `Widget` from the `Impl` instance managed by `std::unique_ptr<Impl>`? Not sure how this answer helps.